# Hyperledger fabric node sdk unable to communicate with orderer container

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have setup hyperledger fabric network on multiple machines using docker swarm network . Now when trying to integrate node sdk with existing running fabric network ,it is unable to communicate with orderer endpoint or any other docker endpoint(via hostname or ip address) and continuously getting `context deadline exceeded` error.
Here is my network-config.yaml file .

Fabric-client only been able to communicate with peer running locally on a system and not been able to make any remote connections either with hostname or via ip address(docker container ip)

```
---
#
# The network connection profile provides client applications the information about the target
# blockchain network that are necessary for the applications to interact with it. These are all
# knowledge that must be acquired from out-of-band sources. This file provides such a source.
#
name: "balance-transfer"

#
# Any properties with an "x-" prefix will be treated as application-specific, exactly like how naming
# in HTTP headers or swagger properties work. The SDK will simply ignore these fields and leave
# them for the applications to process. This is a mechanism for different components of an application
# to exchange information that are not part of the standard schema described below. In particular,
# the "x-type" property with the "hlfv1" value example below is used by Hyperledger Composer to
# determine the type of Fabric networks (v0.6 vs. v1.0) it needs to work with.
#
x-type: "hlfv1"

#
# Describe what the target network is/does.
#
description: "Balance Transfer Network"

#
# Schema version of the content. Used by the SDK to apply the corresponding parsing rules.
#
version: "1.0"

#
# The client section will be added on a per org basis see org1.yaml and org2.yaml
#
#client:

#
# [Optional]. But most apps would have this section so that channel objects can be constructed
# based on the content below. If an app is creating channels, then it likely will not need this
# section.
#
channels:
  # name of the channel
  obaid:
    # Required. list of orderers designated by the application to use for transactions on this
    # channel. This list can be a result of access control ("org1" can only access "ordererA"), or
    # operational decisions to share loads from applications among the orderers.  The values must
    # be "names" of orgs defined under "organizations/peers"
    orderers:
      - node_orderer1st
      - node_orderer2nd

    # Required. list of peers from participating orgs
    peers:
      node_examinationpeerfirst:
        # [Optional]. will this peer be sent transaction proposals for endorsement? The peer must
        # have the chaincode installed. The app can also use this property to decide which peers
        # to send the chaincode install request. Default: true
        endorsingPeer: true

        # [Optional]. will this peer be sent query proposals? The peer must have the chaincode
        # installed. The app can also use this property to decide which peers to send the
        # chaincode install request. Default: true
        chaincodeQuery: true

        # [Optional]. will this peer be sent query proposals that do not require chaincodes, like
        # queryBlock(), queryTransaction(), etc. Default: true
        ledgerQuery: true

        # [Optional]. will this peer be the target of the SDK's listener registration? All peers can
        # produce events but the app typically only needs to connect to one to listen to events.
        # Default: true
        eventSource: true

      node_examinationpeersecond:
        endorsingPeer: false
        chaincodeQuery: true
        ledgerQuery: true
        eventSource: false


    # [Optional]. what chaincodes are expected to exist on this channel? The application can use
    # this information to validate that the target peers are in the expected state by comparing
    # this list with the query results of getInstalledChaincodes() and getInstantiatedChaincodes()
    chaincodes:
      # the format follows the "cannonical name" of chaincodes by fabric code
      - mycc:v2.0

#
# list of participating organizations in this network
#
organizations:
  Examination:
    mspid: ExaminationMsp

    peers:
      - node_examinationpeerfirst
      - node_examinationpeersecond

    # [Optional]. Certificate Authorities issue certificates for identification purposes in a Fabric based
    # network. Typically certificates provisioning is done in a separate process outside of the
    # runtime network. Fabric-CA is a special certificate authority that provides a REST APIs for
    # dynamic certificate management (enroll, revoke, re-enroll). The following section is only for
    # Fabric-CA servers.
    certificateAuthorities:
      - NeduetCertficateServer

    # [Optional]. If the application is going to make requests that are reserved to organization
    # administrators, including creating/updating channels, installing/instantiating chaincodes, it
    # must have access to the admin identity represented by the private key and signing certificate.
    # Both properties can be the PEM string or local path to the PEM file. Note that this is mainly for
    # convenience in development mode, production systems should not expose sensitive information
    # this way. The SDK should allow applications to set the org admin identity via APIs, and only use
    # this route as an alternative when it exists.
    adminPrivateKey:
      path: artifacts/examinationneduet/peer1/keystore/926c45a6a8746e77c2ed81aa74d58a17ca24022c01084bed4c9f1a6ebc965627_sk
    signedCert:
      path: artifacts/examinationneduet/peer1/signcerts/cert.pem

orderers:
  node_orderer1st:
    url: grpc://node_orderer1st:7050

    # these are standard properties defined by the gRPC library
    # they will be passed in as-is to gRPC client constructor
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: node_orderer1st


  node_orderer2nd:
    url: grpc://node_orderer2nd:8050

    # these are standard properties defined by the gRPC library
    # they will be passed in as-is to gRPC client constructor
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: node_orderer2nd



#
# List of peers to send various requests to, including endorsement, query
# and event listener registration.
#
peers:
  node_examinationpeerfirst:
    # this URL is used to send endorsement and query requests
    url: grpc://node_examinationpeerfirst:7051

    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: node_examinationpeerfirst

  node_examinationpeersecond:
    url: grpc://node_examinationpeersecond:7056
    grpcOptions:
      ssl-target-name-override: node_examinationpeersecond

#
# Fabric-CA is a special kind of Certificate Authority provided by Hyperledger Fabric which allows
# certificate management to be done via REST APIs. Application may choose to use a standard
# Certificate Authority instead of Fabric-CA, in which case this section would not be specified.
#
certificateAuthorities:
  NeduetCertficateServer:
    url: http://xxx-xx-xxx-114-210.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7054
    # the properties specified under this object are passed to the 'http' client verbatim when
    # making the request to the Fabric-CA server
    httpOptions:
      verify: false

    # Fabric-CA supports dynamic user enrollment via REST APIs. A "root" user, a.k.a registrar, is
    # needed to enroll and invoke new users.
    registrar:
      - enrollId: admin
        enrollSecret: adminpw
    # [Optional] The optional name of the CA.
    caName: NeduetCertficateServer
```

Any solutions to fix this issue :) Thanks

Comment: Did you find a fix? We are creating a gRPC wrapper to create a workaround

Comment: Though I didnt touch hyperledger fabric for quite some time now but I remember after correctly defining hostnames, it worked . Though on some systems I did notice that this error occurred few times